# Hide parent directory name from VScode breadcrumbs navigation bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there any way to shorten the directory name to access methods & functions easier? don't want to see the full computer's path on the breadcrumbs section.
need to capture this area & I want a cleaner and simple navigation bar! :)
thanks.[image: wanna remove the red section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this setting:

> // Controls whether and how file paths are shown in the breadcrumbs
> view.
> //  - on: Show the file path in the breadcrumbs view.
> //  - off: Do not show the file path in the breadcrumbs view.
> //  - last: Only show the last element of the file path in the breadcrumbs
> view.

```
"breadcrumbs.filePath": "on",
```

That is `Breadcrumbs: File Path` in the Settings UI, try `last` or `off`